# Laravel - How to disable session for specific route?

Tags: laravel

Session driver is set to database currently. Now I want to disable session for some route. I am using laravel 7 in my project. What is the best way to disable the session?

I have tried: in StartSession.php file: \Config::set('session.driver', 'array');

Seems like it doesn't work for me, is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to modify code in files within **vendor** directory is not a good practice as it will get overridden whenever the package is updated.

If you want to remove a middleware from a specific route you can use **withoutMiddleware**

```php
Route::get('/some-endpoint', function () {
        //
    })->withoutMiddleware([StartSession::class]);
```

[Laravel Docs - Middleware - Excluding Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#excluding-middleware)